# Notes client crashes when using object tag and pdf in XPiNC

Tags: xpages, xpinc

I have a PDF file as file resource (test.pdf) in my database and the following xpage which displays it as an embedded object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:panel tagName="object">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="data" value="test.pdf"></xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="type" value="application/pdf"></xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="width" value="600"></xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="height" value="600"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>

    It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. No worries, just <a href='test.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a>
</xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

It works all fine in the web browser (Firefox). When I open the xpage in the Notes client (XPiNC) for the first time the PDF is also displayed embedded. But when I open the xpage a few times the Client crashes.

I use Release 8.5.3FP1.

Do you have any suggestions? Is the use of the object tag forbidden in XPiNC?

---

As recommended in the answer from Simon O'Doherty I checked all files in 'IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT' and 'workspace\logs' folder which were modified since/ after the client crashed.

There were no FATAL in the nsd file.

error-log-1.xml:

```
<CommonBaseEvent creationTime="2012-08-21T22:08:27.093+02:00" globalInstanceId="ELc0a808f50001394acb55ed00000009" msg="Project facet jst.web has not been defined. It is used in plugin org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core." severity="50" version="1.0.1">
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:level" type="noValue">
    <children name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:name" type="string"> 
        <values>SCHWERWIEGEND</values>
    </children>
</extendedDataElements>
<sourceComponentId component="Expeditor 6.2" componentIdType="ProductName" instanceId="1327306362466" location="MBS-86" locationType="Hostname" subComponent="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core" threadId="4" componentType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<situation categoryName="ReportSituation">
    <situationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ReportSituation" reasoningScope="INTERNAL" reportCategory="LOG"/>
</situation>
</CommonBaseEvent>´
```

console_MBS-86_2012_08_21@22_06_40.log :

```
[0548:0002-1230] 21.08.2012 22:27:14,34 DeskClientOpenInt> Calling CreateProgramRCP     pszRCPCmdLine[/authenticate ] bDeskProvisioningRestart [0]
[0548:0002-1230] 21.08.2012 22:27:14,37 DeskClientOpenInt> Executed CreateProgramRCP
[0548:0002-1230] 21.08.2012 22:27:21,35 DeskClientOpenInt> Calling CreateProgramRCP pszRCPCmdLine[/authenticate ] bDeskProvisioningRestart [0]
[0548:0002-1230] 21.08.2012 22:27:21,38 DeskClientOpenInt> Executed CreateProgramRCP
[0548:0002-1230] 21.08.2012 22:27:27,27 DeskClientOpenInt> Calling CreateProgramRCP pszRCPCmdLine[/authenticate ] bDeskProvisioningRestart [0]
[0548:0002-1230] 21.08.2012 22:27:27,29 DeskClientOpenInt> Executed CreateProgramRCP
[0548:000E-0D34]  Thread=[0548:000E-0D34]
[0548:000E-0D34] Stack base=0x05F70084, Stack size = 2560 bytes
[0548:000E-0D34] PANIC: The notes2 process (pid=2052) exited unexpectedly.
```

---

Thx in advance.

Comment: Ok the only SPRs I could find for that are already fixed for that release. 

I tried creating the sample above in a test database, and a PDF printout of this page as a file resource. I then had the database open and close over 30 times. The PDF rendered fine each time and no crash. 

Is there any other factors involved to get the crash to happen?

Comment: Thank you for testing. Due to your results I tested the page on some other computers.The Page with the embedded PDF worked fine and no crash occurs on these other machines. No crash on machines with the following configuration: Win7 64Bit & Acrobat X 10.1.4  | Win XP 32Bit & Acrobat X 10.1.4. Crash on the machine with the following configuration:  Win XP 32Bit & Acrobat Reader 8.1.4.
So the main factor for the crash seems to be the Adobe Reader Version. I don't know if it's a problem with the Adobe Reader or the Notes Client, but in Firefox the xPage is working with Adobe Reader 8.1.4.

Comment: Latest version of reader for XP is 9.5. Can you try upgrading to that and see if it still occurs?

Comment: I already upgraded to Acrobat X/ Reader 10.1.4 an no crash occurs since this update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upgrading from Adobe Reader 8.1.4 to Adobe Acrobat X/ Reader 10.1.4 fixed the problem, no crash occurred since the update.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with crashes.

1. In the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder under your data folder there should be an NSD file. Open that file and search for FATAL and post the fatal thread.
2. If there is no FATAL stack, then check the workspace\logs folder for any Javacores, or Error logs. For the error logs you need to look for SEVERE references, as these are most likely to cause a crash.
3. Also check the XPages logs in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder for any errors.

Without those details it is not possible to diagnose the root cause.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. I added the error log information to the question above.

I found no FATAL in the nsd file and there were no xPages log which were modified since/ after the crash occurs. Ther were only a error log file.